# Is playing carrom-board haram.?

Tags: halal-haram

Is Playing Carrom-board Haram.? Please clarify with Hadith(if available).. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb, Anything in islam in permitted, Unless it is explicitly made haram. So according to this view, playing Carrom-board is not haram. Also, Anything becomes haram, if it takes away remembrance of Allah from you or stop you from doing ibligatory islamic duties.

And Allah knows the best

(Note:I am not a scholar, so you should better consult a scholar for proper fatwa, i just shared what know of)

Comment: +1. I believe there's a Hadith or a scholarly quote where it is said that anything that stops you from remembering your creator and/or causes you to delays/miss salaah is your idol.